# How to Populate ListBox without PostBack in ASP .NET?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, listbox, sqldatasource

My Web Form consists of two Listboxes lstbx01 and lstbx02. lstbx01 is databound to sqlDataSource01 and it Populates on Page Load Event. lstbx02 is set to populate when the selected value of lstbx01 is passed as a Parameter to sqlDataSource02. Everything works fine if lstbx01 has its AutoPostBack property set to True.

I do not want the page to be Refreshed. I want to set the lstbx02 to populate without page being PostBack.

I have tried the below mentioned Code:

```
Protected Sub lstbx02_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstbx02.SelectedIndexChanged
    lstbx02.DataSource = sqlDataSource02
    lstbx02.DataBind()
End Sub
```

This doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that what you are asking would be possible in WebForms. The code you provided would require a postback to transmit the event back to the server so it can be handled.

Is there a specific reason you cannot do a postback? A possible workaround would be to use AngularJS, Knockout, or some other JS framework to populate inputs on the page. You would then need an event handler that either used AJAX to fetch the relevant data or displayed data that has been cached into the page as JSON.

Comment: Thank you @Scott Simontis for the quick response. I don't want to use PostBack because end-user do not want that. I am new to ASP .NET . It would be very helpful if you could walk me through the methods you have suggested. Thanks once again.

Comment: Use AJAX to request to pull the data and update elements on the page. You don't need to worry about postbacks, ASP.Net has some webform AJAX controls out of the box but vanilla AJAX request would also work.